# Python Selenium can't get attribute from element found by class name

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

[image]

```
find_element_by_class_name('css-1rovmyu.eanm77i0').get_attribute('src')
```

This returns None value even though it locates an element.
I was able to get the attribute when I use xpath or id 'img', but can't figure out doing it with class name.

Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple class names there. To locate element by multiple class names you can use css_selector or XPath

```
find_element_by_css_selector('.css-1rovmyu.eanm77i0').get_attribute('src')
```

or

```
find_element_by_xpath('//img[class="css-1rovmyu eanm77i0"]').get_attribute('src')
```

Also you put a dot `.` between the class names. This is CSS syntax, no to be used when selecting by class name.
Also if you put one dot - put the second. Now it's a correct css_selector ;)

Answer (score 0):

this `<img>` tag has 2 classes: `css-1rovmyu` and `eanm77i0` (seperated by space)

you can use `find_element_by_class_name` to find by one class name.
for example: `find_element_by_class_name('css-1rovmyu')`

to find by more than one class name, you can use XPath or CssSelector as @Prophet mentioned.